# Django Model use a seperate model within model as if it is a past of it

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to accomplish the following; I have a model customer and model vendor (and others). I would like to have the fields of the model Location available within the customer and vendor models.

What I can think of is to create the field similar available in the customer and vendor model, and have a seperate save function on each. What is the best approach? I can think of using the save function, and adding additional code to additionally create a Location entry and using that entry to update the location foreign key, meaning I need to have the field available in both Models. But is there a more efficient / proper approach?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        code to create or update the location entry
        super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

````
class Location(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    postal = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location,on_delete=models.CASCADE)```
````

edit:
I guess one way would be to use signals / initial it with post_save, by adding street, number, postal and country to Vendor and Customer model:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Customer)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Vendor)
def my_signal_handle(sender , **kwargs)
     # code here to create a location and update the Customer or Vendor model with the created Location ForeignKey.
```

But, then I would still need to identify the sender to be able to update field "Type" in location, which needs to capture Vendor or Customer in this case. My intend is to use it for more than just Vendor and Customer, and ensure a central data-set is maintained for each Model's addresses to allow also further work with the locational data.

Edit:
I just found the module "[django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)". This would allow me making subclasses of Location, for Vendor and Customer. I'll try this and revert. It might provide the solution in the easiest possible way.